# algorithm for creating shapes out of arrays

Tags: c#, algorithm, 2d

I'm looking for an algorithm which could create shapes based 
on arrays with coordinates. I have two `50`x`50` arrays: one with x and second with y coordinates.

There is always `2500` points. Then I have another `50`x`50` array with my values for coordinates.

I create 3 to 6 areas based on value (for example 0-100, 200-300 and 300-500). Points with certain values creates areas.

I need an algorithm which can calculate if there is only one shape in area or more and fill shapes with colors.
I need that because I must fill shapes with certain colors for each area.
Language is C#.

1. Example points.
2. Expected edges.
3. Expected result

[image: Example picture]

Comment: The input and the concept is not entire clear to me. Can you give some sample data such that we can understand what you want and test an eventual algorithm?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to find the [Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the set.  [Convex Hull Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms).

Comment: See following webpage : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms

Comment: @FelixCastor: no, those shapes aren't convex.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you are correct.  The OP could find the convex hull first then erode the edges to give the desired final product.

Comment: @FelixCastor:  no, this won't work, the shapes are too far from convexity. Alpha shapes could do. https://www.google.be/search?q=alpha+shapes&biw=1680&bih=904&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj76arGibnMAhVCQBQKHboGCq4QsAQIKA&dpr=1#imgrc=_

Comment: You don't give any kind of computable criterion for deciding if a set of points makes a shape.  Also what is the significance of the 50x50 array?  Why not use a 1D 2500-long array?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could use hierarchical clustering to find the clusters.

1. Each point is its own cluster
2. Find two cluster closest together and merge them
3. Repeat until end condition is met

Couple of specifics: In step 2 you could use many metrics to find the closest clusters. Mean-to-mean distance or minimum distance over all point pairs are probably best choices

In Step 3, you can either stop when remaining number of clusters is 2 (or some other number). Or stop when distance is more than a threshold.

To find the actual outline, I suggest coming up with some optimization function that minimizes the length of outline while minimizing the area of the outline. And the some heuristics to optimize the function.

Something like Area - constant*Length.